# Google Web Search API - XMLHttpRequest cannot load Resources

Tags: javascript, json, getjson, google-search-api

I am getting an error as below when I call the Google Web Search Api using JavaScript. When I run the URL on browser, it successfully returns the JSON.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%22opencourseware%22+pdf. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below are the html and JavaScript

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $results3 = $('#results3');

var websearchurl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=\"opencourseware\"+pdf";

$.getJSON(websearchurl , function (json) {

    var count3 = 0;

    if (json.responseData.results) {

        var items3 = json.responseData.results;

        items3.forEach(function (item3) {
            html3 += '<a href="'+item3.unescapedUrl+'">'+item3.unescapedUrl+'</a><br/>';
            count3++;
        });
    }

    if (count3 === 0) {
        $results3.html("No Paper found");
    } else {
        $results3.html(html3);
    }
});
```

Just like to ask if I am missing something because I am also similarly using Youtube and Coursera API and both work fine.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your Help @Marty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use JSONP for Cross Domain request using AJAX.

On you case, this would be like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=\"opencourseware\"+pdf",

    // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
    jsonp: "callback",

    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",

    // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
    data: {
       format: "json"
    },

    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        var count3 = 0;

        if (response.responseData.results) {

            var items3 = response.responseData.results;

            items3.forEach(function (item3) {
                html3 += '<a href="'+item3.unescapedUrl+'">'+item3.unescapedUrl+'</a><br/>';
                count3++;
            });
        }

        if (count3 === 0) {
            $results3.html("No Paper found");
        } else {
            $results3.html(html3);
        }
    }
});
```